# youtube video autoplay on button click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, api, youtube

I'm trying to figure out how to get my youtube video to

1. Not autoplay on website load.
2. I want playback to stop when clicking out of the modal window.

My website: www.pynepoyntdoc.com
Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Below is the javascript code:**

```
enter code here<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#play-video').on('click', function(ev) {

    $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    ev.preventDefault();

}); });
```

**Below is the code for my modal popup window for the youtube video:**

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="padding-top: 8%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="wide-vid">
```

**Below is the code for the 'play video' button:**

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
<p class="slideshow-button">
        <a id="play-video" href="#" class="button-text button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">WATCH VIDEO</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at the available api [here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html) and [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). There are mentions of `player.stopVideo();`, `player.platVideo();` etc.